# I log into a machine using ssh with IP1. When logged in, the output of ifconfig/'ip addr' shows IP2. Why is IP1 and IP2 different?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ip-address

I type:-

```
ssh root@10.2.4.xx
```

So, IP1 :- 10.2.4.xx

When logged into the machine, the output of

```
ifconfig
```

is:-

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
      inet addr:172.17.xx.xx  Bcast:172.17.xx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      .
      .
      .
```

So, IP2 is 172.17.xx.xx.

Shouldn't IP1 and IP2 be the same? Why are they different?

Comment: did you read about public ip and private ip ?

Comment: Don't 10.2.4.xx and 172.17.xx.xx both fall in private ip range? 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 , 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255

Comment: @to-the-person-who-deleted-his-answer... was that supposed to be some kind of a joke? Having me delete the routing table? If it was, it was rather sick on your part, to make fun of people's ignorance. If not, why did you delete the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the computer you are logging to has two network interface cards, one (eth0) configured with IP1 and the other (probably eth1?) configured with IP2. The output of `ifconfig` should show both.

Other less likely reasons are:

- your ssh config file `.ssh/config` has an entry which reads 'host 10.2.4.xx hostname  172.17.xx.xx`
- your /etc/hosts has a line `10.2.4.xx   172.17.xx.xx`
- the `.bashrc` of root on `IP1` contains `ssh -t 172.17.xx.xx`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The machine has just one interface eth0. The other block in the output of ifconfig correspons to 'lo' . The machine doesn't have a .ssh/config file, /etc/hosts or .bashrc don't have those lines either.

Comment: What is the ip of your computer ? in which subnet is your computer ? It could also be that some router between you and the remote computer is doing network address [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)